# XSLT: How get rid of default namespace's prefixes in XPath? (xmlns="...")

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have a template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.1"
    xmlns:d="urn:jboss:domain:1.1"
            >

...

<xsl:template match="//d:interfaces/d:interface[@name='management']/d:inet-address">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

This works.

```
<xsl:template match="//interfaces/interface[@name='management']/inet-address">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Why this doesn't work despite I have a default namespace set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="//interfaces/interface[@name='management']/inet-address">
>      ... 
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> Why this doesn't work despite I have a default namespace set?

**This is one of the most FAQ on any XSLT and/or XPath list**.

**XPath treats any unprefixed name as belonging to "no namespace"** -- regardless of the fact that there may be a default namespace defined and in scope.

**To quote the [W3C XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests)**:

> "*A QName in the node test is expanded into an expanded-name using the
>   namespace declarations from the expression context. This is the same
>   way expansion is done for element type names in start and end-tags
>   except that the default namespace declared with xmlns is not used: if
>   the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null*"

Therefore the template rule above is matching elements that are in "no namespace", but the elements of the XML document are in the `"urn:jboss:domain:1.1"` namespace -- therefore not a single node is matched by the above rule.

Comment: Thanks. I've read the spec before asking, but the explanation seemed so illogical that I thought I didn't understand it. Now I see I did.