# remove namespace prefix with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve a type definition from an external xsd file. In this exemple, my `$attType` has a namespace prefix. But in the XPath I use to get the definition I don't want the prefix. 
The question is : how to ?

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('../file.xsd')//xs:simpleType[@name=$attType]" />
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304592/xslt-how-get-rid-of-default-namespaces-prefixes-in-xpath-xmlns

Comment: I took the dirty solution : substring-after($attType,':')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly less dirty solution is to use `local-name()` to correctly determine the name of the object within the namespace.

This should strip the namespace from elements and attirbutes, and retain text as well:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```